# mysql один ко многим

Tags: mysql

Допустим есть три таблицы (человек, вид спорта, количество забитых голов)
как их связать внешними ключами? если человек может участвовать в нескольких видах спорта,и в таблице забитых голов, хранится инф. по всем голам человека по каждому виду спорта (т.е. комбинация вид спорта/забитые голы в этой табл. не уникальна)

и как вычислить среднее забитых голов по каждому виду спорта

Comment: ну так структуру базы вы вроде и сами написали. в третьей таблице id-записи, id-человека, id-вида-спорта, голы. Хотя возможно каждый гол вообще отдельной строкой. Или делаете уникальной связку id-человека_id-вида-спорта тогда храните в ней единственное число общее кол-во голов данного человека

Comment: проблема что я не знаком сильно с mysql :)

Comment: И что такое среднее забитых голов по виду спорта. Я понимаю по виду спорта "суммарно голов", Может вы имели ввиду среднее кол-во на одного человека по виду спорта ?

Comment: скорее среднее количество, т.е. сумму поделить на количество

Comment: Поделить сумму на количество чего ? Вообще есть функция avg() для получения среднего, главное в group by верно задать до какой степени мы группируем, а это как раз зависит от того что такое "среднее по виду спорта" и от того в каком виде голы хранятся отдельными записями на каждый гол или одной строкой человек-спорт-кол_во

Comment: такая структура должна быть :) 

вася забил 5 голов по футболу
вася забил 3 гола по футболу
вася забил 6 голов по футболу 
вася забил 4 гола по баскетболу
в среднем по футболу вася забил 4.6, по баскетболу 4 
и так по каждому человеку

Comment: Так что вы хотите то получить в ответе. Вы структуру уже сами совершенно точно сформулировали, осталось дать колонкам названия. А запрос при такой структуре вообще элементарный `select avg(cnt) from gols group by people_id, sport_id`

Comment: какие таблицы с какими колонками создавать) и как их связывать в mysql workbech

Comment: Ну вот прямо как вы в впоросе написали такие и создавать: люди, в которых ID человека и видимо ФИО и еще что нибудь о человеке полезное. Виды спорта ID и наименование. И голы ID-записи, ID-человека, ID-спорта, кол-во голов.

Comment: как вместо id вывести имя ?

Comment: `select p.name, avg(cnt) from guals g, people p where p.people_id=g.people_id group by p.name,p.people_id,g.sport_id` ну и название спорта по аналогии добавлять

Comment: непонимаю, у меня три таблицы.

people(id,name)
sport(id, name)
goals(id,poeple_id,sport_id,gol)

Comment: или как сделать вывод в третьей таблице, не id а name =) прости я нуб)

Comment: ну так по аналогии с написанным. добавить в from третью таблицу, в where условие что ее ID=sport_id из голов ну и имя в список выборки